# Remove wpautop from all posts/pages except my custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

My whole theme uses `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` which strips the p tags and lines breaks from the output of the WYSIWYG. I have a custom post type `events` that I would like to bring back the auto p tags and br tags for, but JUST on that custom post type. Is there a way to make sure that filter doesn't get removed on `events`.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a conditional test against the current post type, like this:

```
if ( 'events' != get_post_type() ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Manu will probably work for you, but it will fail if you have a query with events and posts as the post_type. Or two different queries on the same page. The solution is to check whether each post is of the events type and add or remove the filter accordingly.

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'wpse_257708_the_post', 10, 1 );
function wpse_257708_the_post( $post ) {
  if( 'events' === $post->post_type ) {
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  } else {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
  }
}
```